# How to fix an image height inside UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JKTD.jpg)I have a UIImageView inside a UIView inside collection view cell but the image getting bigger in its height than its superview even if I did all the constraints (top, bottom, left, right). 
how can I fix it?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width:DeviceSize.screenWidth - 32, height: DeviceSize.screenWidth/2)
}
```

Comment: 1 - check cell size. 2 - check image view size. 3 - check constraints. Guess your image just not clipped, `imageView.clipToBounds = true`

Comment: did you try `imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill` or `.scaleAspectFit`

Comment: try imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill with imageView.clipToBounds = true 
or imageView.contentMode = . scaleAspectFit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set,

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //you can change it as per your requirement..

imageView.clipToBounds = true
```

Instead of doing it programatically, you can also set them in the `storyboard` itself, i.e.

[image]

Comment: +1 as PGDev's this usually works for me. For example, If your original image is rectangle and image view is square,Aspect fit makes sure aspect is maintained without stretch and 'Clip to Bounds' take care of unpleasant(not used area) in view.

Comment: it worked fine but seems something wrong with shadow code when I use it to draw shadow around the image it makes this miss.
layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        layer.shadowOffset = offSet
        layer.shadowRadius = radius

Comment: `Shadow` won't work with `clipToBounds = true`. Try setting `clipToBounds = false` and `contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`.

Answer (score 0):

@PGDev answer is correct but in this condition, you should use `.scaleAspectFill` instead of `.scaleAspectFit` this will make your image centered

imageView.clipToBounds = true //and this will cut the extra content of image which is out of the view frame